# Change to logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) while executing Python program

Tags: python, logging, stream

// , The one line answer to "how do I set my logging level to debug?" is usually something like the following:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

However, one may be tempted to change it later, back to something like INFO.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

This does not work, however. `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`, if run again at the same scope in the same process, will not result in a change to the level of the messages logged.

The official Python documentation, near the middle of https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file, lists the following:

> The call to `basicConfig()` should come before any calls to `debug()`, `info()` etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

Neither, however, does `Logger.setLevel()` work for this.

The following code attempts to set a lower log level:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("setting logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)")
logging.debug(myLogger.getEffectiveLevel())
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING) # This does nothing. 
logging.getLogger('root').setLevel(level=logging.WARNING)
logging.debug(myLogger.getEffectiveLevel())
logging.debug("logger root, currently at " \
            + str(logging.getLogger('root').getEffectiveLevel()) \
            + " is enabled for" \
            + str(logging.getLogger('root').isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)))
```

This results in the following output:

```
DEBUG:root:setting logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
DEBUG:root:10
DEBUG:root:30
DEBUG:root:30is enabled forFalse
```

It seems like one cannot "set" a Logger to a lower level of verbosity without access to something else created with `logging.basicConfig()`.

## How does a Python script change its logging level halfway through execution?

Answer (score 0):

> `logging.disable(logging.INFO)` → disable messages at `logging.INFO`
>   and lower, until...
>
> `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)` → resume normal logging

Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.disable

Use this to temporarily throttle logging output.
It temporarily overrides the log levels for all loggers.
If you need to shut down logging, use the creatively named [`logging.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown)

First of all, [`logging.basicConfig()` is a constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), which creates a [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) object to connect to the root logger.

Logging levels are just integer constants, not magic properties of a Python script.

To actually change the level for that specific logger, `root`, you may need to access the `StreamHandler` created for it by [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).